# Mount a network share to QNAP using SSH

Tags: qnap

I would like to pull files from a network share to my QNAP device. 
In windows i would type net use **\MyDevice\MyShare /User:...** and then **copy \MyDevice\MyShare\FileFilter Localpath**

o  How do I mount the network share to the QNAP using SSH?
o  Where are my Volumes at the QNAP? I did not find them

Answer (score 3):

In the local filesystem of your QNAP there is a `/share` directory. It contains symlinks to all shared folders that have been set up. Even external storage options like USB harddrives are symlinked there.
It is also the mountpoint for the qnap volumes.

You can check this by just using the `readlink` command.

```
[/] # readlink -f /share/Music
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Music
[/] #
```

A network share can be mounted on the qnap by various protocols. (e.g. nfs, cifs). If you are still on QTS 4.2 and did not update to QTS 4.3 yet, you could try [this third party app](https://www.forum-nas.fr/viewtopic.php?t=6448) (qpkg) to support sshfs.

Comment: QNAP 4.3+ doesn't support SSHFS! You still need the third party app! Install it from entware opkg sshfs - 2.10-1 - Mount remote system over sftp.